# Liquibase creating master.xml startegy

Tags: liquibase

Looking for possiblity to automaticly import all *.xml files to master.xml. Already we have alot includes like

```
 <include file="${classpath}/config/liquibase/changelog/examle001.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
```

in master and it often causing merge conflicts. I think should be an strategy to auto import all files from path to master.xml

Comment: what about [includeAll](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/includeall.html)

Comment: It's open source - better to submit a pull request than a question on Stack Overflow. If you can't write the code yourself, submit it as a bug/feature request at https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues

Comment: thanks @bilak this is exactly what I need